# Charkra UI Flex vs. Stack

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

I'm trying to build a mental model of when I should use Stack (inc. VStack and HStack) vs. Flex. Could somebody please explain the difference? I didn't get much from reading the documentation. What situations particularly call for using Stack and which ones call for Flex?

Answer (score 3):

[From the documentation:](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/stack#notes-on-stack-vs-flex)

> The `Stack` component and the `Flex` component have their children spaced out evenly but the key difference is that the `Stack` won't span the entire width of the container whereas the `Flex` will. Another thing to note is that the items in both `Stack` and `Flex` are aligned in the center by default.

Or here:

[Flex and Spacer vs Grid vs Stack](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/flex#flex-and-spacer-vs-grid-vs-stack):

> The `Flex` and `Spacer` components, `Grid` and `HStack` treat children of different widths differently.
>
> In `HStack`, the children will have equal spacing between them but they won't span the entire width of the container.
> [...]
> With `Flex` and `Spacer`, the children will span the entire width of t he container and also have equal spacing between them.

For me personally, it generally boils down on how much of the behavior I want to customize. If it's not more than a simple row or column of items, I'm using `Stack`, if I need to customize the items width and spacing further, I tend to use `Flex`.

Comment: Looking at the source, they're actually functionally almost identical. The behavior the docs describe is not in the code. The only real difference is that stack has an option to wrap the children and use dividers. But by default, they're both just a container with display: flex.